# Backup ext4 data to exFAT partition

Tags: backup, external-hdd, ext4, exfat

I have a computer running Ubuntu 16 with a bunch of ext4 HDDs mounted inside a samba share that I use as a local NAS.

I don't want to use RAID because I want to be able to shut down the computer, take one of these HDDs, and plug it on another computer in another geographical location and have it working right away.

I initially wanted to use exFAT for the partitions because it is more universal than ext4 (I can plug it on Windows and macOS without installing any 3rd party software) but, since there is no journaling for this format, I ended up deciding against it.

But now I want to add a backup routine with rsync+cron so that the content of each ext4 HDD is regularly copied to another ext4 HDD of similar size (this is in addition to cloud backup), so I'm wondering:

**Can I use the exFAT format on the backup HDDs? This way the ext4 partitions data would be backed up to exFAT partitions. Or would you advise against it? Why?**

My thinking is: this way I get the journaling on the main ext4 disk and I can take out the backup disk to another location and have it working directly on Windows/macOS whenever I need to.

Bonus question: I'm still pretty new to Linux so is rsync+cron the right tool for this type of backup job?

Comment: I should also point out that permissions and ownership are not important for the files I store on those HDDs

Comment: If just data, you can reset ownership & permissions when restored to  Linux formatted partition(s). Best practice for Backups - theFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992 Discussion of issues on rsync bash file &  rdiff-backup  - TheFu
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224428

Comment: Great question. I just bought an external SSD that came formatted with a [1TB](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#1TB) exfat partition. I'm thinking about the same things you mention as I want to use this drive for backup. I do want to preserve permissions, however. Yet, I like how exfat is more cross-platform by default, which would allow me to use the drive for transporting files between platforms, in addition to linux backup. I'm thinking I may want to backup to something based on tar, which I think would preserve permissions even if residing on an exfat partition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advise you against using `rsync`. You should use either `rdiff-backup`, Duplicity, or Borg Backup.

`rsync` is great for mirroring – that is: syncing – folders. You, however, probably want a backup. Imagine you accidentally delete something, then your cron job starts a sync before you can stop it. This means you just lost that data, even though you thought you had a backup. But you only had a mirror. Now if you already made a copy of that copy, you can get your data back as long as that's not already overwritten, too. But if you don't notice your mistake for some time, your data is lost.

Now, there is an rsync switch (`-b`/`--backup`) to prevent this. But you're probably still better off using a tool which is actually designed for making backups.

`rdiff-backup` is such a tool. It does, however, lack encryption.

Duplicity offers encryption. I did, however, make the personal experience that it doesn't restore data reliably. That is, when I tried to get a folder back to a previous state, the one file I really cared about just wasn't restored. And I know that file existed before for months because I just accidentally screwed it up, right before I wanted to restore it. Duplicity wouldn't let me restore that file and when I tried to get the folder back to various points in time, all of which I would've been fine with because there were no major changes to that file for months, it just didn't put that file in the restored folder and didn't even print a hint indicating that that file was missing.

I don't know whether this is actually a problem with Duplicity or whether it's a problem with Deja Dup as I used Deja Dup (which uses Duplicity, which in turn uses `rsync`, btw.) for backing up. I did, however, try restoring the file/folder both via Deja Dup and directly via Duplicity. It didn't work.

About half a year ago, a friend of mine asked me about how I do my backups. The reason she asked me was because she experienced the exact same problem with Deja Dup.

As my trust in Deja Dup was already gone after I experienced the problem myself, I switched to Borg Backup, which I recommend you should too.

Borg Backup takes a bit to get started on but once you know how it works, it's great. It offers versioning, encryption, compression, and deduplication. Backups with Borg Backup are faster than with Deja Dup and you get to enjoy awesome features like being able to mount your backup repository.

That is, you issue a mount command and then enter the location you mounted your repository to. You will then see a list of backup labels as folders. You can enter any one of these folders and look for your files. No need to restore them revision by revision. They're just all there in the mounted repo.

This means you can use normal command-line features and tools on those revisions. For example, I recently found out that I accidentally deleted my Firefox desktop file some time ago. Didn't notice for weeks. A simple

```
ll */home/christoph/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

in the mounted directory gave me a list of all the revisions containing that file. I simply copied the newest one out. But if you wanted, you could take that list and do a diff on the results to see what changed without having to restore anything first. Plus, mounting and searching the repo was way faster than the time Deja Dup takes to just figure out what file is gone.

If you use Borg Backup, it will actually keep track of ownership and permissions without the file system in the backup location having to support ownership or permissions as those are encapsulated by Borg.

Borg can be used perfectly well with cron jobs. It's just a single command you need to issue. There is an archive name you need to specify which needs to be a different one for each backup. If you issue the commands by hand, you can write something more meaningful in there. I simply use `date +%c` for archive names because my backups are created automatically.

Storing your first backup on a FS with journaling is certainly a good idea. As you then only create other backups and it's not terrible if you have to throw the FS your 2nd backup is on away because it got compromised when the power went out, using a non-journaling FS for it is acceptable.

You can sync this second backup from the first one via `rsync`. There is no problem with this as you already made sure you can go back to previous versions via Borg Backup, and – if you want – Borg already took care of encryption, too.

Comment: Borg Backup does indeed look very nice. I only need to be able to take out 3 of the HDDs with me, not all of them, so the option of having ext4 backups for all disks and an additional copy (not necessarily a full blown Borg Backup) in exFAT just for those 3 is something that could work well, that I hadn't thought of. Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain all that.

Comment: **+1** for recommending BorgBackup!  **;-)**

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about Borg. Awesome!